# Можно ли сделать резиновый шрифт в css?

Tags: шрифты, css

Скажите, можно ли сделать шрифт на сайте резиновым — размер которого будет изменяться в зависимости от изменения размеров браузера?

Comment: Можно. Самому, как я понимаю, будет вам сложно. Поэтому, можете использовать готовые плагины, например, этот [FlowType][1].

   [1]:http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Comment: Да, именно это я и имел в виду. А чтобы самому делать, где можно посмотреть? Хотелось бы самому понимать. У нас же, насколько я знаю, размер шрифта в процентах не привязывается к размеру браузера или контейнера.

Comment: @ahel73, это через js делается, последний раз, когда я смотрел в эту сторону, это был просто подбор ширины делением/умножением на два (flowtype судя, по исходнику этим не занимается, а значит, на экзотических шрифтах может весьма сильно ошибаться).

Comment: @ahel73, ну там решался вопрос умещения строки в блок определенной ширины. Делали так: перебором находили оптимальный размер шрифта (так, чтобы не вылазил за ширину блока и был при этом максимального размера), делается это примерно как в алгоритме отгадывания числа - берем заведомо много, - если вылазит делим попалам, если не вылазит, добавляем половину от разницы того, что вылазил, к тому, что не вылазил, как только результат становится меньше минимального шага, считаем последний "не вылазит" за ответ.

Comment: Наверное, нет, можно попробовать сымитировать с помощью calc, но что-то я не уверен.

Comment: @ahel73, в общем случае так, но иногда нужно смотреть в профайлер.

Comment: @ahel73, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Да, можно. Даже без вмешательства javascript. **[Вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/8sdv14k2/)**:

```
.demo {
    font-size: 3vw; /* 3% of viewport width */
}
```

Обязательно прочитайте вот эту статью:

**[Viewport Sized Typography](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)**

**[Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw)**
**IE 9+, Firefox 19+, Chrome 20+, Safari 6+, Opera 23+**