# Резиновый текст (CSS)

Tags: css3

Доброе утро:).
Меня интересует такая тема, как сделать так что-бы h3 подстраивался под размер изображения и уменьшал свой размер, мне нужно что-бы его размер был 25px исходя из макета, но в мобильных версиях его размер уменьшался до адекватного и не имел подобного переноса строк, как это реализовать?
Заранее благодарен :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Media queries` и `white-space` помогут Вам!

Comment: Возможно, поможет ответ на этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356949/Можно-ли-сделать-резиновый-шрифт-в-css/