# Размер текста относительно ширины блока

Tags: css

Есть заголовок внутри адаптивного блока.

Необходимо чтобы сам текст занимал свободное пространство родительского блока по ширине и соответственно увеличивался и уменьшался в размерах.

```
<div class='container'>
 <h1>Заголовок</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size

Comment: Извините, я плохо понимаю английский язык. Но как я понял, там речь идёт о медиа запросах. Данный вариант также не имеет место быть, т.к придётся писать слишком много лишних запросов создавая новый блок и.или "формат" блоков.

Comment: Возможно есть решение от яваскрипт (в нём я тоже не силён) которое позволяет высчитать ширину блока и относительно данной ширины увеличить или уменьшить шрифт?

Comment: вот вариант еще такой - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/w34a1f0t/1/, более подробно https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант на CSS.**

`vw` - еденица измерения, равная проценту ширины документа:

```css
div{   
    font-size: 8.1vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>Некоторый тестовый текст</div>
```

Он довольно неточен, поэтому я поставил  `white-space: nowrap;`

**Вариант с масштабированием.**

Блок с текстом масштабируется с помощью JS и CSS `transform`

```js
function fillDiv(div, proportional) {

  var div=$('#test')
  var currentHeight = div.outerHeight();
  var currentWidth = div.outerWidth()+3;
  var availableHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var availableWidth = window.innerWidth;

  var scale = availableWidth / currentWidth;

  div.css({
    "left": "0px",
    "top": "0px",
    "transform": "scale3d("  + scale + ", " + scale + ", 1)",
    "transform-origin": "0 0"
  });
}
fillDiv();
$( window ).resize(fillDiv)
```

```css
#test{
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Некоторый тестовый текст</div>
```

Стырено и адаптировано из [amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/webapps/docs/automatically-scaling-an-element-to-fill-the-screen)

Answer (score 1):

1. Обернём текст инлайн-элементом (в нашем случае это `<span>`) для того, чтобы вычислять ширину текста. Добавим для этого элемента свойство `white-space: nowrap` — так при инкрементальном увеличении текст не перенесется на другую строку и высчитываемая ширина не изменится.
2. Проверяем что больше — ширина страницы или ширина текста. Если текст больше, то в цикле уменьшаем его до тех пор, пока он не станет меньше. Если текст меньше, то в цикле увеличиваем его. Если в каком-либо из этих циклов произошел перебор с увеличением или уменьшением, то откатываем изменения назад и выходим из цикла.
3. Навешиваем на событие `resize` исполнение этой функции. Чтобы она не вызывалась при каждом событии и чтобы не сильно нагружать браузер, добавим функцию `debounce()` — так она вызовется один раз спустя 250 мс после окончания события.

P.S. пример не слишком хорош, потому что будет слишком часто дергаться DOM и начинаться перерисовка страницы, так что рекомендую подумать над тем, чтобы его улучшить :-)

```js
start();

window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(start, 250));

function getCurrentFz(selector) {
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(selector, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'),
    fontSize = parseFloat(style)

  return fontSize;
};

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    let context = this,
      args = arguments,
      later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    },
    callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

function start() {
  let body = document.body,
    bodyWidth = body.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    selectorInner = document.querySelector('h1 span'),
    fz = getCurrentFz(selectorInner);


  if (bodyWidth > selectorInner.offsetWidth) {
    while (bodyWidth > selectorInner.offsetWidth) {
      fz += 1;
      selectorInner.style.fontSize = fz + 'px';

      if (bodyWidth < selectorInner.offsetWidth) {
        selectorInner.style.fontSize = fz - 1 + 'px';
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    while (bodyWidth < selectorInner.offsetWidth) {
      fz -= 1;
      selectorInner.style.fontSize = fz + 'px';

      if (bodyWidth > selectorInner.offsetWidth) {
        selectorInner.style.fontSize = fz + 1 + 'px';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Some text in header</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Довольно интересная задача. чтобы её решить нужно знать

1. ширину контейнера
2. fontSize текста
3. Ширину текста

Получаем коэффициент: fontSize делим на ширину текста

Умножаем ширину контейнера на этот коэффициент

Получившееся значение будет являться размером шрифта в пикселях которое нужно применить к тексту чтобы тот занимал всю ширину контейнера.

Киллер фича этого решения в том, что коэфициент мы должны рассчитывать только один раз для определённого текста, а затем только умножаем его на ширину контейнера чтобы "растянуть" текст.

```js
let child = document.querySelector('.child');
const k = child.computedStyleMap().get('font-size').value / child.getBoundingClientRect().width;

let observer = new ResizeObserver((mutations) => {
  const containerWidth = mutations[0].contentRect.width;
  child.style.fontSize = k * containerWidth + 'px';
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.parent'));
```

```css
.parent {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fec;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #fec;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">Широко</span>
Изменяй ширину →
</div>
```

До этого решения я 10 лет назад додумался сам )

https://github.com/jt3k/text-autofitter (там можно поиграть в демо)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте относительные единицы rem, em. Еще можно использовать vw, вот стаття с ришением похожей проблемы как у вас. [Статья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356949/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%B2-css)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в статье описывается решение относительно размеров окна, а rem это относительная единица значение которой объединено параметрами шрифта. То есть, если я изменю размер блока, размер шрифта останется фиксированным и никак не примет относительных значений.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```js
$('.jsFontSize').each(function(){
  var fontSize = 14;
  var rowHeight = $(this).height();
  while(rowHeight>20){
      fontSize=fontSize-1;
      $(this).css({fontSize: fontSize+'px'});
      rowHeight = $(this).height();
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 14px;
  min-height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.jsFontSize {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="jsFontSize">
    Текст текст текст текст текст текст
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="jsFontSize">
    Текст текст текст текст текст текст
    Текст текст текст текст текст текст
    Текст текст текст текст текст текст
    Текст текст текст текст текст текст
    Текст текст текст текст текст текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: пример не работает  .. как минимум в Хр и старых броузерах

Comment: в каком именно браузере не работает? если вы смотрите в старом ие, то нужно jquery со 2-ой заменить на 1-ую

Comment: Нет не ие ! А яндэкс браузер в Хр , не работает а точнее текст вообще мизерного размера

Comment: так в этом и суть, я так и поняла, что нужно сделать, чтобы текст был в одну строчку и уменьшался относительно ширины экрана, или я не правильно поняла?)

Comment: А я понял что типа шрифт сам уменьшиться должен, с изменением размера экрана или div

Comment: @kizoso Относительно блока а не экрана) Чуть позже я попробую все варианты которые мне предложили, но пока кандидатом на решение является ответ в комментарии | вот вариант еще такой - jsfiddle.net/soledar10/w34a1f0t/1, более подробно github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js - Пользователь "soledar"