# Как высчитать размер шрифта относительно ширины блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно вычислить размер шрифта, чтобы текст занимал всю ширину блока? Текст может быть как из одного слова, так и из нескольких, но в одну строку.

Comment: На этот вопрос уже отвечали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653093/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от конкретной задачи... Советую обратить внимание на величины  `em, rem, vw, vh, vmin, vmax`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  width: 40vmin;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 10vmin;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="ns">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: В вопросе не спроста указаны тэги javascript и jquery. WV не кроссбраузерно, и также размер шрифта должен высчитываться автоматически при смене текста в блоке.

Comment: Виктор, те величины которые я в ответе указал, всеми браузерами поддерживаются...  Ну, а если `IE 6 7 8 9  10` тоже поддерживать должны, тут уж извини....  Я пас...

Comment: Ты просто поэкспериментируй данными величинами, увидишь, как это удобно...

Comment: Я не спорю, что это удобно :-) IE 9,10 нужны :-(

Comment: Сожалею, Виктор... Ну тогда пройди по ссылке под вопросом, там есть решение....