# Как сделать адаптивный размер текста относительно ширины блока?

Tags: html, css

Нужно менять `font-size` относительно длины текста, чтобы вписывался во всю ширину блока.

Как такое сделать, желательно без js?

```css
.menu {
  width: 58px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.menu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.35em 0.15em 0.45em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
  height: 48px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 100%; /* ??? */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a>Menu 1</a>
  <a>Menu 11</a>
  <a>Menu 122</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Размер текста относительно ширины блока](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653093/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Это совсем не то, `vw` тут никак не подойдет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью svg

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

text {
  transform: translate(10px, 50px);
  font-size: 62px;
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
      <text>TEXT</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```