# Резиновый шрифт

Tags: css, css3, шрифты

Как с помощью css сделать резиновый шрифт? тоесть чтоб он расстягивался не пропорционально

Comment: Не пропорционально чему?

Comment: без соблюдения пропорций высоты и ширины

Comment: Слишком размытый вопрос. Может есть конкретные примеры?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли сделать резиновый шрифт в css?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356949/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82-%d0%b2-css)

Comment: Смотрели такой [пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/332939/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)?

Comment: Ситуация такова: сайт полностью резиновый, тоесть по ширине и по высоте он растягивается в независимости от размера окна. Есть блок, в котором должен быть текст и этот текст должен также растягивать по ширине и по высоте

Comment: грубо говоря, как будто это изображение. оно растягивается не соблюдая пропорций. можно вытянуть его на всю высоту экрана, но при этом по ширине с узить

Comment: вот такой https://youtu.be/CmcN0nwI16w нужен эффект

Answer (score 0):

Если я тебя правильно понял, тебе поможет css свойство **transform**.
С его помощью можно масштабировать элемент в котором находится шрифт.

```
transform: scale(1,2);
```

Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/ynk0t1qh/

Comment: вот такой youtu.be/CmcN0nwI16w нужен эффект

Comment: Да! Вы правильно поняли, но мне нужно чтоб шрифт трансформировался в зависимости от размера окна/блока